# Trying to send proper header with Express, Tedious, while accessing Azure SQL

Tags: node.js, express, azure-sql-database, httpresponse, tedious

My backend gets a request to get records from an Azure SQL db. To manage this requests I'm using Express in Nodejs, and Tedious (to connect to DB). When the request to the appropriate route comes in, Tedious opens the connection with db, queries it, and it should send the response back to frontend.

However, the code responds before I have an answer with from the db, and thus when I go to send the *real* (the actually desired) response, Express tells me it already sent headers back (the dreaded: 'Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client').

After debugging quite a bit (using several console.log(JSON.stringify(resp.headersSent)); ) to see when was the response actually sent, I noticed that it's sent the moment I connect with Azure (see below).

I'm not sure if I'm missing something (though I already checked the documentation for all those programs quite a bit), but how can I control when the response is sent? Or, is there another way of doing this.

I omitted several of the other routes for brevity. Other routes work fine and thus I know code connects well to Azure db, and frontend does query backend correctly. Help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
const Request = require('tedious').Request;

const config = {
  authentication: {
    options: {
      userName: "xxxx", 
      password: "xxxx" 
    },
    type: 'default'
  },
  server: "xxxx", 
  options: {
    database: "xxxx",
    encrypt: true
  }
};

const app = express();
app.use(express.json({type: '*/*'}));
app.use(cors({ origin: '*' }));

app.get("/allproj/", function (req, resp) {
  const q = `select Title, Report_Date, Project_Number, Phase_Code, Items_No, PId from projec order by PId desc`;
  let ansf = [];
  
  const connection = new Connection(config);

  connection.on('connect', (err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {                  //this is the moment the headers are sent, 
                              //seemingly with positive response from connection
      queryItems(q);
    }
  });
  
  queryItems = (q) => {

    request = new Request(q, function (err, rowCount) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(rowCount + ' rows pulled');
        connection.close();
      }
    });

    request.on('row', function(columns) {
      let ans = [];
      columns.forEach(function(column) {
        ans.push(column.value);
        if (ans.length === 6) {  // I know each row is 6 cols long
          ansf.push(ans);
          ans = [];
        }
      });
      console.log('ansf length: ' + ansf.length);
      resp.send({ ansf });          // This is the response I would like to return
    });

    request.on('done', function(rowCount) {
      console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
      connection.close();
    });

    connection.execSql(request);    
  };

  resp.redirect("/");
});

app.listen(3000, process.env.IP, function() {
  console.log("Started OK...");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove resp.redirect("/");
As it is already transferring your request to "/" and when control come at resp.send({ansf}), It gives you error.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good catch. I still had to modify a couple other things to make the code send the response when I wanted, but your answer helped a lot!